# Renaming a file path for use in excel

Tags: excel, path

='C:\user\Sonny\desktop[Book1.xlsx]sheet1'!$A$1

Hello, i have the above to reference a closed workbook. Could you advise another way so that i don't need to specify the user\sonny\ as the file is used by several users? and that it works on excel as a closed reference?

Appreciate your assistance.

Thanks

I did some search, I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: This looks to be on Sonny's desktop. How are other people accessing this file?

Comment: This is more of a Windows question than an Excel question.  Are these users on different PCs?  Then you will have to add the machine name as a fully-qualified URL.  There are ways to obfuscate the `users/sonny`  part by forwarding the web address and/or creating shortcut directories on sonny's machine (assuming the file system is NTFS).

Comment: Hello, The rest of the user can place all their file on their desktop and the filepath will automatically point to the filepath.  Yeah, there are similarity on question on using ..\desktop , ~\desktop. But specifically in scenario purely for use in simple excel spreadsheets. I found parts of the solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Question is a little unclear - above comments have asked if other users are trying to access Sonny's desktop.

I will take your question to mean that you want the reference to point to the current user's desktop. For example if Sonny opens the file it will point to C:\users\Sonny\desktop, but if Kevin opens the file it will point to C:\users\Kevin\desktop. If that is the case:

If you want the reference to point to the current user's desktop,

Option1: VBA

```
Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\desktop\"
```

Option2: Formulas. But - this will only give you the folder that the current file is saved in, so the user must save this file on their desktop. Then you can concatenate with the file name and sheet / range reference.

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"))-1)
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, VBA is out of the question security reasons and the company blocked it. Yes that VBA code works. Option2 is the answer i need- it pointed me to the right search. Here is part of the  solution: 
cell("filename",A1)

Comment: However, i am still thinking how to add the sheet name and cell reference to a closed workbook. string  concatenation or indirect() doesn't work on a closed workbook reference ( or maybe i errored somewhere).  

Appreciate all your Inputs and time on this. It's awesome. Thanks!